# Using Open Universal Data tool correctly in MapInfo Pro?

Tags: mapinfo, import, dwg

After I lost settings file (MapInfow.prf), I can't properly open data using tool Open Universal Data. Which earlier worked without problems. Now when I try to open the dwg file, the layers are displayed incorrectly.

The layers are covered by the other, buildings are covered by parcels. I'm doing exactly what I always do. What should I setup in the options to correctly open dwg files.

I'm using MapInfo Pro 15.0 32-bit

Comment: Is it just a question of opening the Layer Control and changing the order of the layers? What setting file did you loose?

Comment: I lost MapInfow.prf. Now I see that the parcels (polygons) are not transparent.

Comment: You can make the individual layers transparent